# Kendo DatePicker Angular format Value

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I've got the following DatePicker in a form:

```
<kendo-datepicker
  [format]="'dd.MM.yyyy'"
  [(ngModel)]="contract_start"
  name="contract_start"
></kendo-datepicker>
```

I set the date in typescript like this to the first day of next month:

```
public contract_start = new Date();
this.contract_start.setMonth(this.contract_start.getMonth()+1,1);
```

When I submit the form, the value is not like "dd.MM.yyyy" instead its the javascript format like "2018-03-01T12:21:52.206Z"

In the jQuery+Kendo Version I had the parameter "parseFormat" to set the correct date format.

I was not able to find out how to solve this with the Angular release.

I'm using Angular5 and the latest kendo-ui library via npm.

Thanks for your help.

Greetings
eXe

Comment: The format-input only controls how the `Date` is displayed in the `DatePicker`, the model will still be a `Date` object and not a `string`.

Comment: So that means I've got to convert all date fields in my form with a custom function before submitting the form? Is there no such functionality built in with the kendo ui framework for angular?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: That's absolutely stupid. How do you solve this problem in your projects? Where do you update the values to correct formatted strings?

Comment: Well, we are using the ISO 8601 format for dates (when we send or get data from the server), which is the default when using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`, if I'm not mistaken. So this was never an issue for us.

Comment: The format atribute is for display purposes only.
You don't do the formatting before you submit the forms, you do it on the receiving end. The form submits a date. The receiver then does what it wants with the date it got.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found the alternative to "parseFormat" in the angular release of kendoUI.

So I converted the javascript timeobject on the backend.